# Aws cli not installing in cygwin throwing error

Tags: amazon-web-services, pip, cygwin, aws-cli

These are the error details. Trying to install the awscli through pip. tried wget method as well.

```
$ pip install awscli
 Collecting awscli
Using cached awscli-1.25.53-py3-none-any.whl (3.9 MB)
Collecting PyYAML<5.5,>=3.10
Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
  0 [main] python 2066 child_copy: stack write copy failed, 0xFFFF5480..0x100000000, done 4294923504, windows pid 16392, Win32 error 5
                                                         5496 [main] python 2066 dofork: child 
 2067 - pid 11768, exitval 0x103, errno 11
                                                          ERROR: Error [Errno 11] Resource 
 temporarily unavailable while executing command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
 Installing build dependencies ... error
 ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running in an elevated shell? Start `mintty` with the `run as administrator` option. Also make sure you have installed the right python (probably version 3.9) and some python packages using the cygwin installer, e.g. `setuptools`, 'wheel`. You may need to install the gcc compiler tool chain if anything needs to be compiled. BTW, the safest way to get the right pip for your python is to run `python -m pip ...`

Comment: Are you running Cygwin 64 bit ? Have you tried installing the python39-yaml ?

Answer (score 0):

From [Installing or updating the latest version of the AWS CLI - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html#cliv2-linux-install):

```bash
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

Comment: Not works in cygwin